# Repeated receipt of uncommitted messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is it possible to set up receiving a message from kafka so that the reader receives an uncommited message again and again, and does not take the next offset?
Setting `enable.auto.commit` is equal to false

And I use java and kafka without Spring

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max.poll.records=1` and simply cache&return the singular consumed record "again and again", rather than polling in a loop.

Otherwise, continuing to poll from the same client will seek the offset forward.